CSS negative absolute position inside a scrollable container


    .editor {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 50px;

    }

    .editor-box-with-overflow {
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }

   .editor-box-without-overflow {
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .editor-element {
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .editor-element-label {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        left: 0px;
        top: -20px;
        background-color: green;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: none;
    }

    .editor-element:hover .editor-element-label {
        display: block;
    }
<div class="editor">
    <div class="editor-box-without-overflow" style="background-color:aliceblue ;">
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 0px;top: 0px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 10px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 40px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-box" style="background-color: rosybrown ;">
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 0px;top: 0px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 10px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 40px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="editor">
    <div class="editor-box-with-overflow" style="background-color:aliceblue ;">
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 0px;top: 0px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 10px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 40px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-box" style="background-color: rosybrown ;">
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 0px;top: 0px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 10px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-element" style="left: 40px;top: 30px;">
            Element
            <div class="editor-element-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



I’m working on a drag-and-drop editor where users can add an editor box, within the editor box users can place draggable, movable elements, each element has a specific position and on hover an info label appears above the element (using a position: absolute with a negative offset), This setup works perfectly without an overflow constraint.
However, when I apply overflow: auto to the editor box to handle content exceeding the box size, the info label's positioning breaks when it's near the container's borders. instead of rendering fully, the label gets under the container.
The example above shows one without overflow and one with next to each other
Any idea how to handle such case

When an element is display: none it is really gone, it's not invisible, it's like teleported off the document. So when an element is at that state it takes up no space in the DOM. If it becomes display: anything but none it's teleported back taking up space and pushing anything within it's space and disturbing elements closeby which makes the browser recalculate everything that changed in that instant. Those "labels" are at the highest point  of the stacking order so they do not cause that type of chaos, they are phantoms in the stratosphere.

I don't get this layout even if you had the labels under control, it still looks like bad UX.

i got what you are trying to explain, but this is a simplified version of the actual code, imagine you using paint and drawing rectangles and circles elements, when you hover over an element to edit an info label shows up, the only different here is that the element is scrollable (container element) and contains sub elements, and when the sub element close to the top border for example the label do not overflow above the container element
